# How to count the number of the same items in an array and assign the count to a particular key in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to convert an array like the following:

```js
["Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs"]
```

the the following form:

```js
[
    { x: "Cats", y: 35 },
    { x: "Dogs", y: 40 },
    { x: "Birds", y: 55 },
]
```

where `y` represents the number of the same elements in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlighting use of the efficient, modern `Map`-based approach that can also be found in similar forms in the duplicate:

```js
const getCounts = iterable => {
    const counts = new Map();

    for (const x of iterable) {
        counts.set(x, (counts.get(x) ?? 0) + 1);  // use || for ES6 compat
    }

    return counts;
};

Array.from(
    getCounts(["Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs"]),
    ([x, y]) => ({x, y})
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a faster version using object lookup:

```js
const arr = ["Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Birds"];
const result = Object.entries(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] = (acc[cur] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null))).map(([x, y]) => ({x, y}));

console.log(result);
```

### Edit

As Ry-♦ mentioned, there was a potential bug that the string `"__proto__"` etc. can't be count correctly. So changed from `{}` to `Object.create(null)` to avoid it.

Comment: This can have conflicts with `Object.prototype` properties. Better to use a `Map` if supported (which also allows for types other than strings), or `Object.create(null)` in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `Array#reduce()` to efficiently build a dictionary of `{ x : Animal, y : Count }` objects, and then extract the required array of values from the dictionary via `Object.values()`:

```js
const input = ["Cats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Dogs", "Dogs"]

/* Obtain array of values from reduced dictionary */
const result = Object.values(input.reduce((dict, value) => {
  
  /* Fetch, or insert starting item for value in dictionary */
  const item = dict[value] || { x : value, y : 0 }
  
  /* Increment y counter for item */
  item.y++;

  /* Update dictionary value with item */  
  dict[value] = item;

  return dict

}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

One of the advantages with this approach is that it avoids the [overhead of an extra call to `.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#When_not_to_use_map), making it more efficent.

Comment: or `const result = Object.entries(input.reduce((a, v) => (a[v]=(a[v]||0)+1, a), {}))
.map(([x, y]) => ({x, y}));`

Comment: @JaromandaX yep that'd do it. It's nice to avoid an extra `map()`, when possible :)

Comment: @JaromandaX Lol almost exactly the same answer, didn't even notice

Comment: If worried about efficiency, copying the object every iteration for O(n^2) time should be avoided.

Comment: @Ry- point taken , updated answer